# MySQL: Filter on multiple values in different rows but return only rows that match both values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, filter

This problem has been bugging me for a long time now and i have never been able to realy figure it out.

What I want is to find all products that match several option_ids,

So for example: I want all product ids that have option id 20 and 28. The query should return 2 results. Product id 1 and 4 and not return id 3, because it only matches one of the option ids, not both.

```
| product_id |  option_id |
---------------------------
| 1          |  20        |
| 1          |  24        |
| 1          |  28        |
| 2          |  28        |
| 3          |  19        | 
| 3          |  20        | 
| 3          |  28        |
| 4          |  28        | 
| 4          |  30        |
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM your_table 
WHERE option_id IN (20,28) 
GROUP BY product_id
having count(distinct option_id) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for that, i used to screw around with group_concat to get  that to work, but not anymore

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
  product_id, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT option_id) AS option_count 
FROM t 
WHERE 
  option_id IN (20, 28) 
GROUP BY 
  product_id 
HAVING 
  option_count=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE option_id IN (20,28) GROUP BY product_id
```